# Count controlled loop with button in tkinter

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, button

I want to create some buttons in `tkinter` with a `for` loop that run a function with a parameter but when I click on the buttons they all output `else`. I don't know what went wrong, here is my code:

```
statements = ['print', 'if', 'else']

def ins(state):
  print(state)

  return

count = 0

for x in statements:
  b = Button(self.funcFrame, text=x, command=lambda:ins(x))
  b.grid(row=0, column=count)
  count += 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean: `command=lambda x=x:ins(x))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create buttons in a for loop you can't use command directly. To make it work you should use partial

```py
from functools import partial

statements = ['print', 'if', 'else']

def ins(state):
    print(state)
    return


for count, x in enumerate(statements):
    b = Button(self.funcFrame, text=x, command=partial(ins, x))
    b.grid(row=0, column=count)
```